# SharePoint Online - Document Review Period Set By User

Tags: sharepoint-online, designer-workflow

I have a document library with 7 different content types. I want to allow the users to select a review period (e.g. 3 months, 6 months, 9 months or 12 months) when they create the documents and it trigger an email after it hasn't been modified for that time period.

Ordinarily I would configure each content type to have a set review date (in the Information Management Policy Settings) but that won't work in this scenario.

I thought about using the Information Management Policy Settings to trigger a workflow 3 months after the document is last modified, which then checked a document property column and then looped each week, until it matches the review day but that feels like a big overhead for the workflows, especially on around 1,000 documents.

Has anyone implemented anything similar?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried these solutions yet but I think there are two options:

1. Create a '**Send to Location**' (Site Admin, Under Records Management) and through Information Management Policy
   move the documents to that particular target location /library and
   add a workflow when new item is added to this new location
2. Create a **Content Organiser Rule** (need to activate Content Organizer from Site Settings --> Manage Features) feature based on the date and move/copy
   the content where you can initiate the workflow.

Note, since you are SharePoint Online, Send to location will take few hours to replicate and Content Organiser will take 24 hours to get into action.